# Object-oriented programming. Task

Tags: java

I'm trying to work on one task. But i haven't idea how can i started. I want just simple explain to the tasks condition. Thank you very much for your support.This is the task condition:

Create class HugeInteger -which uses 40 element array of digits to store integers as large as 40 digits each. Provide methods parse, toString, add and subtract. Method parse should receive a String, extract each digit using method charAt and place the integer equivalent of each digit into the integer array.

Comment: Here's how you start: public class HugeInteger. Please, this question demonstrates no knowledge of Java whatsoever, and doesn't state a specific problem. Please consult the Stack Overflow [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on what you can and cannot ask about on this site.

Comment: Didn't they give you a textbook for your class?

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this

```
public class HugeInteger {

    private int[] value;

    private HugeInteger(String s) {
        super();
        parse(s);
    }

    public void parse(String s) {
        //read s and check if it's a valid array of x<=40 digits
    }

    public String toString() {
        //return the contents of int[] value as a readable String
        return null;
    }

    public HugeInteger add(HugeInteger hi) {
        //return the sum of this object and hi
        return null;
    }

    public HugeInteger subtract(HugeInteger hi) {
        //return the difference between this object and hi
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // don't forget to deal with overflows and underflows

        HugeInteger hi = new HugeInteger("10000");
        HugeInteger hi2 = hi.add(new HugeInteger("-10000"));
        System.out.println(hi2.toString()); //expected 0


    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Leo. You help me a lot with this answer. Thank you again.